# ActionBar desaparceu após atualizar o Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, actionbar

Após atualização não aparece mais ActionBar em novos projetos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.softwares.biel.noticiascombar">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.softwares.biel.noticiascombar;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

---

A actionBar só não aparece no projeto, mas no emulador ela aparece!

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Aqui também aconteceu isso, para ela voltar, basta vc clicar naquele olhinho que fica logo acima da view, em seguida marque a opção Show Layout Decorations.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]